# Is anything known about the speed with which viruses spread geographically in R. affinis (or at least bats in general)?

Tags: virology, coronavirus, habitat, bats

RaTG13, which is the closest known relative of SARS-CoV-2 at full genome level, [was](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982220303602) sampled (just) in a *R. affinis* (bat) specimen in Yunnan Province... which is about 1,500 km away from Hubei, the epicenter of the first Covid-19 cluster.

So, what if anything is known about the speed with which viruses spread *geographically* among bats, particularly *R. affinis*? Basically, do we have any idea how long it would take a virus to "travel" in (*R. affinis*) bat populations 1,500 km?

A [paper](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.02.10.942748v2.full.pdf) still in draft estimates that the most recent common ancestor of SARS-CoV-2 and RaTG13 "lived" around 2009.

> the inferred the time to the most recent common ancestor in the recombinant region of the clade leading to RaTG13 and SARS-CoV-2 is no later than 2009 (2003-2013, 95% HPD limit).

I'm trying to figure out if this time frame is compatible in some sense with the speed with which viruses are known to spread in bat populations.

Comment: You can make SIR model acquire the diffusion equation characteristics by adding the spatial variables. That will give you the spatial diffusion (spread) speed.

Comment: Look at the sarbecovirus phylogeny and add the precise locations and years. @Hans we don't have any model for how the different bat caves/species exchange viral strains from years to years, we need to built it directly from the sparse data..